# How do I make 100 calls in the same function, to iterate over api endpoints? [Pokeapi]

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to iterate over 151 pokemon, but the api endpoint looks like this `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1` where 1 is the first pokemon, and i need to iterate through to 151, calling a different endpoint every time.  Is there a better way to do this?  This is the code I have so far, and it doesn't work.

```
let pokeObj = {};

function pokeList() {
const url ='https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        for(let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
            pokeObj += JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            xhr.open('GET', `${url + i.toString()}`, true);
            xhr.send();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you need to wait each request response before sending the next one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
(async () => {

    let pokeObj = {};

    const url ='https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon'
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    for(let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {

         const response = await new Promise(resolve => {

            xhr.onload = function(e) {
                resolve(e.target.response);
            }

            xhr.open('GET', `${url}/${i}`, true);
            xhr.send();

        });

        console.log(response)

    }

})();
```

Each request will be awaited before firing the next one, to be nice to the api server and not executing too many request in parallel.